# Program which counts how many times "th" appears in a text

Tags: file, python-2.7

```
def sequencia(file):
    z=open(file,'r')
    cancion = z.readlines()
    z.close()
    contador=0
    for i in cancion:
        contar = i.count('th')
        contador=contador+contar
    return contador
```

When I run the program it counts 0. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your file is not empty and 'cancion' actually has some lines?

Comment: I had no problem with this code, it works.